# Is it possible to create a organization level section on slack

Tags: slack

I want to group slack channels in the organization by sections, and I am trying to create it for the entire organization to see it by default and not as a custom configuration

Is this possible?

For reference: https://slack.com/blog/collaboration/slack-essentials-organize-your-work-and-conversations